# mysql stop on any warning

Tags: mysql, warnings

I load a huge csv text data into a table.  It shows some warnings but does not show the line of the text file so I do not know which data caused the warnings.
Is there any way that the SQL will stop when it gets any warning?
Or print out primary key so I know which line it is?

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'data.csv'  INTO TABLE T
COLUMNS TERMINATED BY ','  OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES (id, ......);


Warning (Code 1411): Incorrect datetime value: 'Mail' for function str_to_date
Warning (Code 1411): Incorrect datetime value: 'Mail' for function str_to_date
Warning (Code 1411): Incorrect datetime value: 'Mail' for function str_to_date
Warning (Code 1411): Incorrect datetime value: 'Mail' for function str_to_date
Warning (Code 1411): Incorrect datetime value: 'Mail' for function str_to_date
Warning (Code 1411): Incorrect datetime value: 'Mail' for function str_to_date
Warning (Code 1411): Incorrect datetime value: 'Mail' for function str_to_date
Warning (Code 1411): Incorrect datetime value: 'Mail' for function str_to_date
```

Answer (score 0):

show warnings command display the lines causing problemes: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/show-warnings.html

Comment: It does not show which line/row has problem,